# PyTorch LSTM dropout vs Keras LSTM dropout

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to port my sequential Keras network to PyTorch. But I'm having trouble with the LSTM units:

```
LSTM(512,
     stateful = False,
     return_sequences = True,
     dropout = 0.5),
LSTM(512,
     stateful = False,
     return_sequences = True,
     dropout = 0.5),
```

How should I formulate this in PyTorch? Especially dropout appears to work very differently in PyTorch than it does in Keras.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you.

```
lstm = nn.LSTM(
    input_size = ?, 
    hidden_size = 512, 
    num_layers = 1,
    batch_first = True, 
    dropout = 0.5
)
```

You need to set the `input_size`. Check out the documentation on [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM).

---

**Update**

In a 1-layer LSTM, there is no point in assigning dropout since dropout is applied to the outputs of intermediate layers in a multi-layer LSTM module. So, PyTorch may complain about dropout if `num_layers` is set to 1. If we want to apply dropout at the final layer's output from the LSTM module, we can do something like below.

```
lstm = nn.Sequential(
    nn.LSTM(
        input_size = ?, 
        hidden_size = 512, 
        num_layers = 1,
        batch_first = True
    ),
    nn.Dropout(0.5)
)
```

According to the above definition, the output of the LSTM would pass through a Dropout layer.

Comment: PyTorch complains if you set the dropout parameter on a one-layer LSTM.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that will work the same as in TF. About the dropout parameter, the TF docs says "Fraction of the units to drop for the linear transformation of the inputs." So it's the inputs that are dropped. But the PyTorch doc says "If non-zero, introduces a Dropout layer on the outputs of each LSTM layer except the last layer," So here it is the outputs that are dropped. So it appears to me that the dropout is applied at different steps in the computation.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? @BjörnLindqvist

Comment: I was not able to.